# Group table, count rows, pad columns with spaces, and concat everything into one big string in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have already come up with a working formula but I feel like it is horribly inefficient. I feel like there is probably a better way to do this.

I have a table like so:

```
| ID    | Name   | Status    |
|-------|--------|-----------|
| ID001 | User 3 | closed    |
| ID002 | User 5 | cancelled |
| ID003 | User 2 | closed    |
| ID004 | User 3 | pending   |
| ID005 | User 3 | closed    |
| ID006 | User 1 | closed    |
| ID007 | User 3 | hold      |
| ID008 | User 5 | hold      |
| ID009 | User 4 | closed    |
| ID010 | User 3 | closed    |
| ID011 | User 4 | pending   |
| ID012 | User 4 | pending   |
| ID013 | User 2 | hold      |
| ID014 | User 3 | closed    |
| ID015 | User 2 | pending   |
| ID016 | User 2 | closed    |
| ID017 | User 1 | pending   |
| ID018 | User 5 | pending   |
| ID019 | User 2 | open      |
| ID020 | User 4 | hold      |
| ID021 | User 2 | open      |
| ID022 | User 2 | pending   |
| ID023 | User 5 | closed    |
| ID024 | User 3 | closed    |
| ID025 | User 5 | open      |
| ID026 | User 5 | closed    |
| ID027 | User 4 | cancelled |
| ID028 | User 1 | hold      |
| ID029 | User 4 | open      |
| ID030 | User 1 | pending   |
| ID031 | User 5 | pending   |
| ID032 | User 3 | cancelled |
| ID033 | User 2 | closed    |
| ID034 | User 5 | open      |
| ID035 | User 2 | open      |
| ID036 | User 2 | pending   |
| ID037 | User 3 | hold      |
| ID038 | User 4 | open      |
| ID039 | User 5 | open      |
| ID040 | User 2 | pending   |
| ID041 | User 3 | pending   |
| ID042 | User 5 | cancelled |
| ID043 | User 2 | pending   |
| ID044 | User 2 | cancelled |
| ID045 | User 1 | open      |
| ID046 | User 2 | pending   |
| ID047 | User 1 | pending   |
| ID048 | User 2 | cancelled |
| ID049 | User 2 | pending   |
```

I want to group by `Name`, count the number of rows where `Status` is `not` `cancelled`, `closed`, or `hold`. So, using a simple query I get this:

```
=QUERY(
    A2:C,
    "
        SELECT
            B,
            COUNT(A)
        WHERE
            A IS NOT NULL AND
            C != 'hold' AND
            C != 'cancelled' AND
            C != 'closed'
        GROUP BY
            B
        LABEL
            COUNT(A) ''
    "
)
```

Becomes:

```
| User 1 |  4 |
|--------|---:|
| User 2 | 10 |
| User 3 |  2 |
| User 4 |  4 |
| User 5 |  5 |
```

Then I want to concatenate everything into one big string -- but the `Name` column should be padded with spaces on the right such that the numbers on the left line up (`when using a monospace font`), and then pad the total so it is right aligned (`when using a monospace font`).

The idea is, the total/summary table should be in one call whose font will be set to monospace.

I came up with the below formula that works (screenshots below). But I am wondering if there is a better, more efficient way to do this.

```
=JOIN(
    CHAR(10)
  , QUERY(
        TRANSPOSE(
            SORT(
                {
                    UNIQUE(
                        FILTER(
                            IF(Sheet1!B2:B = "", "!!! UNASSIGNED !!!", Sheet1!B2:B) & REPT(
                                " ",
                                MAX(
                                    FILTER(
                                        LEN(Sheet1!B2:B)
                                        , Sheet1!A2:A <> ""
                                        , Sheet1!C2:C <> "closed"
                                        , Sheet1!C2:C <> "cancelled"
                                        , Sheet1!C2:C <> "hold"
                                    )
                                ) - LEN(IF(Sheet1!B2:B = "", "!!! UNASSIGNED !!!", Sheet1!B2:B))
                            ) & " :"
                          , Sheet1!A2:A <> ""
                          , Sheet1!C2:C <> "closed"
                          , Sheet1!C2:C <> "cancelled"
                          , Sheet1!C2:C <> "hold"
                        )
                    )
                  , ARRAYFORMULA(
                        REPT(
                            " ",
                                MAX(
                                LEN(
                                    COUNTIFS(
                                        IF(Sheet1!B2:B = "", "!!! UNASSIGNED !!!", Sheet1!B2:B)
                                      , UNIQUE(
                                            FILTER(
                                                IF(Sheet1!B2:B = "", "!!! UNASSIGNED !!!", Sheet1!B2:B)
                                              , Sheet1!A2:A <> ""
                                              , Sheet1!C2:C <> "closed"
                                              , Sheet1!C2:C <> "cancelled"
                                              , Sheet1!C2:C <> "hold"
                                            )
                                        )
                                      , Sheet1!A2:A
                                      , "<>"
                                      , Sheet1!C2:C
                                      , "<>closed"
                                      , Sheet1!C2:C
                                      , "<>cancelled"
                                      , Sheet1!C2:C
                                      , "<>hold"
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                          - LEN(
                                COUNTIFS(
                                    IF(Sheet1!B2:B = "", "!!! UNASSIGNED !!!", Sheet1!B2:B)
                                  , UNIQUE(
                                        FILTER(
                                            IF(Sheet1!B2:B = "", "!!! UNASSIGNED !!!", Sheet1!B2:B)
                                          , Sheet1!A2:A <> ""
                                          , Sheet1!C2:C <> "closed"
                                          , Sheet1!C2:C <> "cancelled"
                                          , Sheet1!C2:C <> "hold"
                                        )
                                    )
                                  , Sheet1!A2:A
                                  , "<>"
                                  , Sheet1!C2:C
                                  , "<>closed"
                                  , Sheet1!C2:C
                                  , "<>cancelled"
                                  , Sheet1!C2:C
                                  , "<>hold"
                                )
                            )
                        )
                      & COUNTIFS(
                            IF(Sheet1!B2:B = "", "!!! UNASSIGNED !!!", Sheet1!B2:B)
                          , UNIQUE(
                                FILTER(
                                    IF(Sheet1!B2:B = "", "!!! UNASSIGNED !!!", Sheet1!B2:B)
                                  , Sheet1!A2:A <> ""
                                  , Sheet1!C2:C <> "closed"
                                  , Sheet1!C2:C <> "cancelled"
                                  , Sheet1!C2:C <> "hold"
                                )
                            )
                          , Sheet1!A2:A
                          , "<>"
                          , Sheet1!C2:C
                          , "<>closed"
                          , Sheet1!C2:C
                          , "<>cancelled"
                          , Sheet1!C2:C
                          , "<>hold"
                        )
                    )
                }
              , 1
              , TRUE
            )
        )
      , 
      , 999^99
    )
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: My first question would be (and often is)... WHY do you want a final result that is all in one cell, set up the way you show? What is the end use or benefit of that format over any other? Also, your sample shows that all user names are User 1, User 2, etc. Is this representative of the actual format of this data (i.e., they are all of uniform length), or is the actual data of varying lengths? Will every user appear in the final results? I can see ways to trim down what you've done, but I first want to fully understand the goal and parameters before giving it further consideration.

Comment: I have another application that has very limited capabilities. All it can do is pull values from a single cell and display them in monospace. And Name can be variable length.

Comment: I need this data to be visible to my users. This is the easiest and fastest way for me. Not perfect but I’m operating a lot of constraints.

Comment: Why do the numbers need to appear to be flush-right with variable spacing after the colon, as opposed to flush-left with a uniform one space after the colon? Also, you haven't yet answered this question: Will every user appear in the final results?

Comment: It seems you've lost interest in this post. I've had it up in a separate browser window for the last couple of days, but I'm going to close that now. I visit Stack once every couple of weeks. I'll check back next time to see if you've replied.

Comment: Doh! So sorry -- got caught up with my next issue. I want the numbers to appear flush right because that is how numbers are usually aligned. Makes it easier for viewers to see. And yes, every user will appear in the final result.

Comment: This is not something I need. This is something I am trying to accomplish to compensate for security policies that don't let me do things the right way (a custom integration). The only way I can do what I need is pulling the data from a single cell in a Google Sheet and displaying it on the front-end using a `monospace` font. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your answers to my questions in comments, this is what I came up with (without spending hours at least):

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(CHAR(10),SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B&REPT(" ",(MAX(LEN(B2:B)+1)-LEN(B2:B))),B2:B<>"")),1,1)&":"&(REPT(" ",(MAX(LEN(COUNTIF(FILTER(B2:B,NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C,"cancelled/closed/hold")))),FILTER(B2:B,NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C,"cancelled/closed/hold")))))))+1)-LEN(QUERY(FILTER({B2:B,C2:C},NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C,"cancelled/closed/hold")))),"Select COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col2) ''"))))&QUERY(FILTER({B2:B,C2:C},NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C,"cancelled/closed/hold")))),"Select COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col2) ''")))
```

It cuts your formula down by 433 non-space characters (i.e. by nearly half).

Typically, I explain my formulas. But in this case, I trust you won't mind if I leave it to you to tear apart and study the formula.

** EDIT BY IMTheNachoMan **

Unminified formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
    JOIN(
        CHAR(10),
        SORT(
            UNIQUE(
                FILTER(
                    B2:B
                    &
                    REPT(
                        " ",
                        (
                            MAX(
                                LEN(B2:B) + 1
                            )
                            -
                            LEN(B2:B)
                        )
                    ),
                    B2:B <> ""
                )
            ),
            1,
            1
        )
        & ":" &
        (
            REPT(
                " ",
                (
                    MAX(
                        LEN(
                            COUNTIF(
                                FILTER(
                                    B2:B,
                                    NOT(
                                        ISNUMBER(
                                            SEARCH(
                                                C2:C,
                                                "cancelled/closed/hold"
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),
                                FILTER(
                                    B2:B,
                                    NOT(
                                        ISNUMBER(
                                            SEARCH(
                                                C2:C,
                                                "cancelled/closed/hold"
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ) + 1
                )
                -
                LEN(
                    QUERY(
                        FILTER(
                            {
                                B2:B,
                                C2:C
                            },
                            NOT(
                                ISNUMBER(
                                    SEARCH(
                                        C2:C,
                                        "cancelled/closed/hold"
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        "Select COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col2) ''"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        &
        QUERY(
            FILTER(
                {
                    B2:B,
                    C2:C
                },
                NOT(
                    ISNUMBER(
                        SEARCH(
                            C2:C,
                            "cancelled/closed/hold"
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            "Select COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col2) ''"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I haven't finished going through how the formula works but it breaks under some condition. For example, if you change ID009 name to "Alpha User" then the formula yields "#N/A".

Comment: I didn't know you could use `/` in `SEARCH` like that. Cool!

Comment: Change all of the rows to `closed` except the first one and it'll yield invalid results. I see what you're doing now and see whats wrong. The `QUERY` may yield a different # of rows than the first part (`UNIQUE`) because not all names may have an open row....

Comment: Keep in mind that, from "out here," someone can only go on the information as it has been provided to us. This is why I asked if every user listed in the sheet will definitely turn up in the final result (to which you answer that, yes, they would). If that is not actually true (which would be the case if all rows were "closed" except the first one)—or if any other facets differ between what was shown and what you're trying to do—then you'll have problems, particularly in a formula of that length. Hopefully, it at least gave you more tools to consider.

Comment: Ah. I had misunderstood that question then. I'm going to keep playing with your formula. Do you mind if I edit your question to pasted an un-minified version of it?

Comment: I don't understand your request: "Do you you mind if I edit your question to pasted an un-minified version of it?" Are you asking if you can repost my formula in a different format? If so, that's fine.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. I meant to ask if I could edit your answer to reformat. Will do. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, do you know where I can read up on this `/` in `SEARCH`? I don't see it listed in any official documentation. Are there other tricks?

Comment: The / is not anything special. It's just a separator. It could have been any symbol that was sure not to turn up in actual data. In your case, in a practical sense, its really more for readability, since there is no change of a bleed-through word being formed by the end of any of your words and the beginning of the next. As such, the SEARCHes here would work without any separator symbol at all. But I use best-practice techniques by default. In other instances that may apply to future site visitors, it will matter.

Comment: I am an idiot. You're searching for `C2:C` in `cancelled/closed/hold`. That makes so much more sense then what I am doing -- searching for `cancelled` OR `closed` OR `hold` in `C2:C`. Thanks!

Comment: If you are curious, I did a performance comparison of the two formulas and there is only a ~10 ms difference in the two, on average.